# GC SQL 2nd Generation Set Root Password "Failed to Load"

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I Created google cloud 2nd generation GC SQL instances. when i go to gc sql instances>access control>users it showing me failed to load.
previously i am able to set root password so that i can create my db and db users.

[image]

Comment: Please further describe your problem.  Inlining your images would improve the chances of getting a useful answer.  Also, please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Can't put a comment, but I am also getting this same issue. For now use the first gen setup and it all works. Hopefully G will spot all this missing elements - including "Create Database" like with the first gen setup

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-cloud-sql-discuss/Mk5rvbtISbs See reply to the same post on the mailing list.

Answer (score 0):

Per the discussion in the [discussion linked](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-cloud-sql-discuss/Mk5rvbtISbs) in a comment to the above answer. This is a known issue with 2nd gen Google Cloud SQL instances. Right now as a workaround the root password can be set via the Google Cloud Shell interface:

```
gcloud sql instances set-root-password
```